# The problem is finding the largest negative, least positive numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

In general, the task, most of which I did:
[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8bY.png)

My problem is 2 things: 1) How to find the smallest positive and largest negative number. 2) How to find their position (and yes, I could not find the positions of the smaller and maximum numbers either).

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        const int rows = 5;
        const int cols = 5;

        int pos = 0;
        int neg = 0;
        int null = 0;

        int iMin = 0;
        int jMin = 0;
        int iMax = 0;
        int jMax = 0;

        double average;
        double sum = 0;

        ifstream matrix("C:\\Folder\\Matrix.txt", ios::in);

        int arr[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix >> arr[i][j];
                cout << arr[i][j] << " " << "\t";
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

        matrix.close();

        ofstream final_matrix("C:\\Folder\\Final matrix.txt", ios::out);

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i][j] > 0)
                    {
                        pos++;
                    }
                    else if (arr[i][j] < 0)
                    {
                        neg++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        null++;
                    }

                    if (arr[i][j] < arr[iMin][jMin])
                    {
                        iMin = i;
                        jMin = j;
                    }

                    if (arr[i][j] > arr[iMax][jMax])
                    {
                        iMax = i;
                        jMax = j;
                    }



                    sum += arr[i][j]; 

                }
            }
            int prod = rows * cols;

            cout << "The number of positive numbers in the matrix: " << pos << endl;
            final_matrix << "The number of positive numbers in the matrix: " << pos << endl;

            cout << "The number of negative numbers in the matrix: " << neg << endl;
            final_matrix << "The number of negative numbers in the matrix: " << neg << endl;

            cout << "The number of zeros in the matrix: " << null << endl;
            final_matrix << "The number of zeros in the matrix: " << null << endl;

            cout << "The minimum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;
            final_matrix << "The minimum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;

            cout << "The maximum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;
            final_matrix << "The maximum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;

            cout << "Arithmetic mean of the matrix: " << sum / prod << endl;
            final_matrix << "Arithmetic mean of the matrix: " << sum / (rows * cols) << endl;

            final_matrix.close();

        cin.get();
    }
```

Below I also present the result of the code (it showed only what is displayed on the console; in addition, the results are still saved in a separate file).
[Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s954b.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets for that.

Here is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<set>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 5;

    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int null = 0;

    int iMin = 0;
    int jMin = 0;
    int iMax = 0;
    int jMax = 0;

    //for larget negative
    int ineg=0;
    int jneg=0;
    //for lowest positive
    int ipos=0;
    int jpos=0;

    double average;
    double sum = 0;

    ifstream matrix("Matrix.txt", ios::in);

    int arr[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix >> arr[i][j];
            cout << arr[i][j] << " " << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    matrix.close();

    ofstream final_matrix("Final_matrix.txt", ios::out);

                set<int, greater<int>> s;

                set<int> s1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    pos++;
                }
                else if (arr[i][j] < 0)
                {
                    neg++;
                }
                else
                {
                    null++;
                }

                if (arr[i][j] < arr[iMin][jMin])
                {
                    iMin = i;
                    jMin = j;
                }


                if (arr[i][j] > arr[iMax][jMax])
                {
                    iMax = i;
                    jMax = j;
                }

                sum += arr[i][j]; 

                if(arr[i][j]<0)
                {
                    s.insert(arr[i][j]);
                }

                if(arr[i][j]>0)
                {
                    s1.insert(arr[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        int prod = rows * cols;

                set<int>::iterator it1 = s1.begin();
                set<int, greater<int> > ::iterator it = s.begin(); 

        cout << "The number of positive numbers in the matrix: " << pos << endl;
        final_matrix << "The number of positive numbers in the matrix: " << pos << endl;

        cout << "The number of negative numbers in the matrix: " << neg << endl;
        final_matrix << "The number of negative numbers in the matrix: " << neg << endl;

        cout << "The number of zeros in the matrix: " << null << endl;
        final_matrix << "The number of zeros in the matrix: " << null << endl;

        cout << "The minimum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;
        final_matrix << "The minimum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;

        cout << "The maximum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;
        final_matrix << "The maximum number in the matrix: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;

        cout << "The lowest positive number in the matrix: " << *it1 << endl;
        final_matrix << "The lowest positive number in the matrix: " << *it1 << endl;

        cout << "The largest negative number in the matrix: " << *it << endl;
        final_matrix << "The largest negative number in the matrix: " << *it <<endl;

        cout << "Arithmetic mean of the matrix: " << sum / prod << endl;
        final_matrix << "Arithmetic mean of the matrix: " << sum / (rows * cols) << endl;

        final_matrix.close();

    cin.get();
}
```

If you want coordinates also, use unordered_map where you can insert a pair of your coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain what unordered_map is and how it is applied?